# Dynamically calculing the if function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some calculations in `compute` function.

```
function compute() {
  var c = $('select#time_from_hour').val();
  var d = $('select#time_from_minute').val();
  var e = $('select#time_to_hour').val();
  var f = $('select#time_to_minute').val();
  var g = $('input#date_from').val();
  var h = $('input#date_to').val();
  var hour1 = g + ' ' + c + ':' + d;
  var hour2 = h + ' ' + e + ':' + f;

  hour1 = hour1.split("/");
  var hour1 = hour1[1] + "," + hour1[0] + "," + hour1[2];
  var timestamp = (new Date(hour1).getTime() / 1000) + 7200;
  $('#total_hour1').val(timestamp);

  hour2 = hour2.split("/");
  var hour2 = hour2[1] + "," + hour2[0] + "," + hour2[2];
  var timestamp = (new Date(hour2).getTime() / 1000) + 7200;
  $('#total_hour2').val(timestamp);

  var x = -$('input#total_hour1').val();
  var y = -$('input#total_hour2').val();
  var total_time = x - y;
  result = total_time / 86400;
  new_number = Math.ceil(result);

  if (isNaN(new_number)) {
    var new_number = 0;
  }
  $('#finish_day').val(new_number);

  if (parseInt($("#finish_day").val()) < 4) {
    $('#get_car, #return_car').not(this).children('#return_car option[value=' + this.value + ']').attr('selected', true).siblings().attr('disabled', true);
    $('#three_day').show(2000);
  } else {
    $('#get_car > option, #return_car > option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#three_day').hide(2000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
}

$('select#time_from_hour').change(compute);
$('select#time_from_minute').change(compute);
$('select#time_to_hour').change(compute);
$('select#time_to_minute').change(compute);
$('select#return_car').change(compute);
$('select#get_car').change(compute);
$('input#finish_day').change(compute);
```

I try to force a script to dynamically recalculate the `if` function when the data in the input field `#finish_day` is changed.

```
if (parseInt($("#finish_day").val()) < 4) {
  $('#get_car, #return_car').not(this).children('#return_car option[value=' + this.value + ']').attr('selected', true).siblings().attr('disabled', true);
  $('#three_day').show(2000);
} else {
  $('#get_car > option, #return_car > option').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#three_day').hide(2000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

It changed only when I change the data in `#get_car`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/W7NHK/25/

---

The problem is as follows:

I have a reservation form, where I use the datepicker, where I have two dates boxes: the start and the end, and two select  form fields with a list of available cities. Depending on the selected dates the script calculate the number of days.

If the number of days is less than 4, on one of the select lists of cities (the second - City2) changes the availability of active cites and automatically selects the city selected in the first list (City1). So if we select on the first list city – Katowice for example,  and the number of days is less than 4 on the second list script automatically marked the Katowice city and the others cities will be inactive (disabled).

The problem begins when the number of days is greater than 4 days. Both lists are fully active and you can choose any city, without restrictions. If you select different cities and then change the date, and number of days go down to 3 (for example) the whole script should recalculate values and set in the second window, the city which  was chosen in first window (City1 = City2). Unfortunately, this does not happen.  Additionally, in the second list, you can choose any city – all are active. The whole script is recalculating only if you select the city from the first list.

Comment: Noone can change the data in finish_day since it is readonly. You need to trigger $("#finish_day").change(); But what is the point? it is compute that changes the value, so no need to call compute when the data changes since compute changed it.

Comment: the `#finish_day` is calculating when you change the data in two date field

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal failing example of the problem you're trying to describe? There's a lot of repeated code here, so having just one simple function here that demonstrates the issue could also lead to better code.

Comment: Don't ANSWER your own question - instead EDIT the new information into the original question